# XCode 4.2 Rename Target

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am trying to create a LITE version of my iPhone app by using different targets. So I have duplicated the release target 'Checklists' and it will name it 'Checklists copy'. I have managed to change the name of the actual .app that is created but not the target name. Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So the .app is named via the product name. The target name is an identifier for the build settings, which are actually built using a scheme. The name you see when selecting what to build is a scheme, and you can rename those by clicking on the bar and going to "manage schemes".

To rename the target you just click on the name and it will turn into an edit box.

[image: Targets]

Comment: http://ge.tt/8dKxulB?c Screenshot, I dont know the best way to add a screenshot...

Comment: I feel like a noob, I thought I'd tried that already, many thanks